# .htaccess not affect subdirectories?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, directory, subdirectory

How I can make my file .htaccess not affect subdirectories?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks!

Comment: The rewrite rules don't(or should not) affect subdirectories, that's what this line does `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`, ie. `!-d` means not a directory.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

make another .htaccess in subdirectory that contrast your parent directory .htaccess setting.